# What are some reasons for a Hyperledger Peer container to go down?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been experimenting on a Hyperledger Fabric test network with 4 peers (all peers on the same machine) and I have noticed that the peer containers (along with the corresponding chaincode containers) go down when I stress the network.
 
I am trying to pinpoint the reason why this happens, but I am quite new to Hyperledger Fabric and Docker and I don't know if I am missing something. 
 
The peer containers go down when I try to ingest a big amount of data into the network at once (i.e. in a single transaction). At first I though that the problem was with the volume of my data (the documentation specifies 80-90MB as the max supported transaction payload size), but the containers fail with much less data than the specified max size (30-35MB in a single transaction)... 
 
I tried chunking the data and issuing multiple transactions (one per chunk), but the containers still fail. I have tried 10MB and 20MB chunks so far.
 
**What do you believe it is the problem here?**
How much I am stressing the test network with back-to-back calls, given that it runs on a single machine? 
The chunk size, possibly causing any buffer overflows (i.e. data volume explosion when the peers generate the read/write set for each transaction)?
Etc...
 
TBH, I believe all the aforementioned are to blame, but if you have anything in mind to narrow down the scope of the issue, please share with me.
Thanks :)
 
**EDIT:**
**configtx.yaml snippet**

```
# Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
BatchTimeout: 10s

# Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
BatchSize:

    # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
    MaxMessageCount: 10

    # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch.
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 500 MB

    # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
    # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
    # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
    PreferredMaxBytes: 4 MB
```

**Successful data submission output for a 2 data chunks:**
chunk size was set to 10MB, resulting into 1 chunk of ~8MB and 1 chunk only a few KB (because it only keeps some metadata)

```
#0 Transaction id is: ccea3260d2b92bfa8678426a876edad1e0322b21395c5210169f54acd14b945e
#1 Transaction proposal successfully sent to channel.
    Chaincode invocation proposal response #0 was good
#2 Looped through the proposal responses all_good= 1
#3 Registered the Tx Listener
#4 Transaction has been submitted.
#0 Transaction id is: a685edfe9421dd0f88d048ea3f7851c2f553af759cba84f88a8f438ae096def2
#1 Transaction proposal successfully sent to channel.
    Chaincode invocation proposal response #0 was good
#2 Looped through the proposal responses all_good= 1
#3 Registered the Tx Listener
#4 Transaction has been submitted.
#5 Received Tx Event
The chaincode invoke chaincode transaction has been committed on peer localhost:7051
Transaction ccea3260d2b92bfa8678426a876edad1e0322b21395c5210169f54acd14b945e is in block 7
0_metadata { is_completed: 'false', status: 'PENDING', pending: 1 }
#5 Received Tx Event
The chaincode invoke chaincode transaction has been committed on peer localhost:7051
Transaction a685edfe9421dd0f88d048ea3f7851c2f553af759cba84f88a8f438ae096def2 is in block 8
0 { is_completed: 'true', status: 'VALID', pending: 0 }
```

**Unsuccessful data submission output for 8 data chunks:**
chuck size also set to 10MB, 1 chunk is for metadata and the others are ~10MB each. The following output is printed for each chunk that fails to be submitted

```
...
#0 Transaction id is: 066ef0c386b8986bb1a2497e613b7bc1e0a2edc12308fd56ed0d9f5931cb58ea
#1 Transaction proposal successfully sent to channel.
    Chaincode invocation proposal response #0 was bad!
#2 Looped through the proposal responses all_good= 0
#3 Registered the Tx Listener
2021-03-30T10:00:03.913Z - error: [Channel.js]: sendTransaction - no valid endorsements found
Error: no valid endorsements found at Channel.sendTransaction (/home/erodotos/Desktop/gitub_project_stavroulla/Model-Meta-Database/app/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:3003:10)
at submitPage (/home/erodotos/Desktop/gitub_project_stavroulla/Model-Meta-Database/app/server.js:169:23)
at async /home/erodotos/Desktop/gitub_project_stavroulla/Model-Meta-Database/app/server.js:601:13
```

Comment: Hi Σταυρούλα & welcome to Stack Overflow, can you share the error or any logs that you have the moment of the failure?

Comment: You are likely running out of memory.

Comment: Could you check the value of the `AbsoluteMaxBytes` variable in the `configtx.yaml` file you used to configure the channel? If that value is less than the size you want, try increasing it.

Answer (score 0):

1st better to look at peer logs. you can use **docker logs containerid**
This might give you some hints. If you need more information set the change the log level to debug using **FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG** environment variable.